# Почему index.html не рендерится локально при использовании React-router?

Tags: javascript

Использую react-router v4 в своем приложении. На локалхосте все работает, хостинг на гитхабе тоже работает. 
Но если открыть index.html локально (без локалхоста), то приложение просто не рендерится. Убираю роутинг, все норм. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при открытии index.html локально приложуха тоже работала ?

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Router, Route } from 'react-router';
import './index.css';

import App from './containers/App/App.js';

import Resume from './components/Resume/Resume.js';
import Biography from './components/Biography/Biography.js';
import Abstract from './components/Abstract/Abstract.js';
import Library from './components/Library/Library.js';
import Links from './components/Links/Links.js';
import Search from './components/Search/Search.js';
import IndividualSection from './components/IndividualSection/IndividualSection.js';

import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createBrowserHistory()
const store = configureStore();
const baseUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Route path={ baseUrl + "/" } component={App} />
      <Route exact='' path={ baseUrl + '/' } component={Resume} />
      <Route path={ baseUrl + "/bio" } component={Biography} />
      <Route path={ baseUrl + '/diss' } component={Abstract} />
      <Route path={ baseUrl + '/library' } component={Library} />
      <Route path={ baseUrl + '/links' } component={Links} />
      <Route path={ baseUrl + '/zvit' } component={Search} />
      <Route path={ baseUrl + '/ind' } component={IndividualSection}/>
    </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: А чему у вас будет равен `baseUrl` при запуске локально?

Comment: В общем-то его можно и убрать, но при запуске локально он се равно равен пустой строке. Так что это не сильно влияет на результат. Я его добавлял, когда приложуха не работала на github-pages.

Comment: Вы были правы, без baseUrl хоть что-то рендерит. Теперь он рендерит App, а все остальное нифига. Буду дальше разбираться

Comment: ...приложуха!!!

Comment: что вас смущает в слове "приложуха"?)